# I need to make a label expand based on the window size

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-layout

I wanted to make a title label that spans the top of the screen with the text in the middle. this works when the window opens but if I go into fullscreen, the label only spans half the length. if I make the label bigger, the text is not in the middle. it's a win-lose situation. any way to make both of them work?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

Title_Font = ("Hallo Sans", 20, "bold")
MyBlue = '#30D5C8'

Home = tk.Tk()
Home.title("Guitar Bud")
Home.geometry('1000x700')
Home.configure(bg='grey')

ExersisesLbl = tk.Label(Home, width=60, height=1, bg='black', fg=MyBlue, text='Exersises', font=Title_Font, anchor=CENTER)
ExersisesLbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky='ew')
```

Comment: `Home.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @JacksonPro said, use grid_columnconfigure().

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

Title_Font = ("Hallo Sans", 20, "bold")
MyBlue = '#30D5C8'

Home = tk.Tk()
Home.title("Guitar Bud")
Home.geometry('1000x700')
Home.configure(bg='grey')
Home.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

ExersisesLbl = tk.Label(Home, width=60, height=1, bg='black', fg=MyBlue, text='Exersises', font=Title_Font, anchor=CENTER)
ExersisesLbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky='ew')

mainloop()
```